# Do Until Nothing Found

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I am working on a macro to go through stock data. When no data is available on a given date, the data shows "-" in those rows. I need to delete those rows.
I have come up with a macro that deletes the first row found. I need to keep it going until all rows with "-" are deleted.

How can I do this with a Do Until loop?

```
Sub removejank()
'
' removejank Macro
    Cells.Find(What:="-", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
    If ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the formatting for the cells that contain the `-`? IOW, is this an actual text `-` or is it a result of the accounting or currency format where entering a `0` will display as `-`?

Comment: And what column(s) would these cells be in? Edit: I see that it appears to essentially be the entire row of data. So if you were only to look at column A for example, would that be sufficient? (We can search all columns, but restricting to 1 may speed up your code a bit).

Comment: The "-" is an actual text, no formulas or calculations behind it. The data is structured to have separate columns for date, open, high, low, close, volume of a particular stock. If any Information is missing, the columns B to G would all contain this "-" sign. So yes, If we only checked any singular column from B to G, it would be sufficient to determine that the row should be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible ways to loop through and delete rows.

In your example, using `Activate` significantly slows down runtime when you are looping data. `.Activate` is almost completely avoidable in just about every circumstance. Obviously, I see that what you've done was with the macro recorder, so it's understandable that it's there.

Anyway, try the following code. This only looks in column A. If you need to look in a different column, then change the "1" in this line:

```
If .Cells(r, 1).Value = "-" Then
```

To the column # you want to look in. Also, you will likely need to change the sheet name in this line:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
```

to match the sheet name you are wanting the code to run in.

---

So the way this method of the many methods out there works is that you will loop through every line in column A with `For r = 1 ...`. Each loop iteration you are looking in the cell's value. If it equals `-`, then the If statement is true and proceeds to add the cell to our special range that we named `delRng`. You are not actually deleting the row just yet, only tracking them in this range.

Once finished, you will take all the single cells in the `delRng`, and using the `.EntireRow` property, delete them all at once. This is generally faster than deleting rows one at a time.

```
Public Sub RemoveJunk()

    Dim delRng As Range, r As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For r = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = "-" Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Cells(r, 1)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Cells(r, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End With
    
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for this awesome explanation. I will try it out immediately!

Comment: the only thing i needed to change was the first If indentation to reference cells(r,2) because the "-" signs would only show up in columns B to G. It works perfectly otherwise. I was trying to go about solving this via some sort of find loop when it turns out the way you did it is so much easier! I actually follow your logic, it's just that I haven't seen some of the methods and other thinsg like the Union for example, but I'm still learning. Your help is greatly appreciated